# How to make accessible pdfs with ConTeXt/LuaTeX and open-source tools

Tags: luatex, pdf, context, tools, accessibility

I recently watched [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJAna6wyPu0&list=PLLt9mKFAx-FYOYtzes-knpRC2wyOyVGum&index=24) about PDF accessibility in LaTeX, and I was wondering how well it was supported by ConTeXt/LuaTeX. From what I've gathered, LuaTeX makes it easier by using UTF8 and TTF fonts, and there is support in ConTeXt for tagged PDFs (I found the `\setuptagging` command in the [Interactivity](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/interaction.pdf) manual). However I'm still missing a few things:

- I didn't find how to manually add tags (for example an alt text for an image)
- I can't find any open-source and Linux-compatible tools for *testing* accessibility (by showing the tags or the TTS transcript or something like that). In his presentation Ross Moore uses Acrobat Reader; is there no open-source equivalent for Linux?
- I can't find an open-source pdf reader that actually implements pdf accessibility. I tried having Okular read [this pdf](https://www.maths.mq.edu.au/%7Eross/TaggedPDF/Week13-2017-with-solutions-actualtext.pdf) (which is supposed to be accessible) but the result was really bad (it reads `2^5 = 32` as `twenty five equals thirty two`). This makes me wonder: is it even possible to have accessible pdfs as of today, or should we use better-supported formats (like HTML)?

Comment: Only the first bullet point is on-topic for us: the rest is general about PDFS

Comment: I don't know a tool for linux, but for windows pac3 is free and quite ok, https://www.access-for-all.ch/ch/pdf-werkstatt/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac/download-pac-3.html

Comment: I think accessibility on PDF is kind of broken in general. Specifications are messy and Adobe does whatever they want, whenever they want. If you want to be *sure* about it, you should stick to html.

Comment: You can use `pdfinfo -struct`  or `pdfinfo -struct-text` to view the tagged contents of a tagged PDF